# Is there a way to apply an Animation Preset - Text Effect onto a shape?

Tags: after-effects, animation, presets

I have a few bullet points as so:

[image: Screenshot of Bullet Point]

I would like to apply an `Animation Preset > Text > Blurs > Bullet Train` to it... But I want the effect to include the blue circle. I've tried applying directly, parenting, and pre-composing. None had the desired result. Is there a way to get the `Text Effect` onto the shape layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There sadly does not appear to be a direct way to do it, however you can approximate it by using a Directional Blur on your shape layer with a 90 degree orientation and then applying a fade in.  If you mess with the keyframes a bit, you should be able to get it to look like a constant animation.

Answer (score 0):

What about cheating by using a font that has numbers in circles? This, for example: http://www.fontscape.com/explore?3O4

Won't work for more than 9 bullet points though.

Comment: Those don't give you control of both colors. The only way to rig it up that way would be to use a large solid circle in text (oversize bullet in most typefaces) and then the number in a separate layer on top of it with the keyframes aligned.